# Inconsistent value of C struct returned from a shared library

Tags: c

I'm trying using C program to interact with a .so shared library. The shared library is built from C using command:`gcc -fPIC -shared schoolimpl.c -o libschoolimpl.so`, with following source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct student {
    uint32_t id;
    char* name;
    uint32_t age;
} student_t;

void print_student(struct student* stu_ptr) {
    printf("print student { id = %lu, name == %s, age == %lu }\n", stu_ptr->id, stu_ptr->name, stu_ptr->age);
    return;
}

struct student* generate_student(uint32_t i, char*n, uint32_t a) {
    struct student* stu_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    struct student stu = {
        .id = i,
        .name = (char*)malloc(strlen(n)*sizeof(char)),
        .age = a,
    };
    strcpy(stu.name, n);
    stu_ptr = &stu;
    print_student(stu_ptr);
    return stu_ptr;
}
```

Then I build a C main program with command `gcc main.c -lschoolimpl -o main` to call the shared library:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct student {
    uint32_t id;
    char* name;
    uint32_t age;
} student_t;

void print_student(struct student* stu_ptr);
struct student* generate_student(uint32_t id, char*name, uint32_t age);

int main() {
    struct student* stu_ptr = generate_student(10, "Jack", 1908);
    print_student(stu_ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, I got the following result:

```
print student { id = 10, name == Jack, age == 1908 }
print student { id = 10, name == Jack, age == 0 }
```

I want to know why is the data of `struct student` cannot be read again. Actually the similar situation happens when I use `Rust` to interact with .so shared libraries built by `C` with `FFI`. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You’re allocating memory and then making the pointer point to a local, temporary object. That is a memory leak and a dangling pointer. You need to use the allocated memory, not create a local object.

Comment: Get rid of the stack variable `stu` and _only_ use `stu_ptr`. You can't [meaningfully] return a pointer to `stu` (local variable) to the caller as `stu` goes out of scope. Also, `name = (char*)malloc(strlen(n)*sizeof(char))` should be: `name = (char*)malloc(strlen(n) + 1)` I think your interest in designated initializers has led you astray. Replace all `stu` stuff with: `stu_ptr->id = i; stu_ptr->name = strdup(n); stu_ptr->age = a;` It's just as fast [or faster] than the initializer approach.

Comment: You probably wanted to do `*stu_ptr = stu;` instead.

Comment: `.name = (char*)malloc(strlen(n)*sizeof(char)),` you need one more byte for the terminating `NUL`.

Answer (score 2):

This is textbook undefined behavior. Your `stu_ptr` points to local memory allocated on the stack for `generate_student`, which is then freed. After the function returns, `stu_ptr` is a *dangling pointer*, which means attempts to dereference it or access its memory will result in *undefined behavior*.

If you don't have a good reason to return a pointer, then just return the struct `stu` and change the return type to `struct student`.

However, since you mention FFI, I assume this is being passed over a language boundary, which *is* a valid reason to return a pointer. In that case, just set up the fields directly on the pointer, not on a local value.

```
struct student* generate_student(uint32_t i, char*n, uint32_t a) {
    struct student* stu_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    stu_ptr->id = i;
    stu_ptr->name = n;
    stu_ptr->age = a;
    return stu_ptr;
}
```

and then, of course, don't forget to provide a `free_student` function, so that you don't end up leaking memory or forcing your users to do the same.

Comment: `.name` is a `char *` so it needs a `malloc` (as in the question) or `strdup`

Comment: this answer also has classic UB, you strcpy to a char* that points nowhere.

Comment: @pm100 Oops, you're right! Too much C++, too little C, and sometimes you miss things :)